# Selenium testng xml issue

Tags: annotations, testng

I am trying to include a method in testng.xml file which is present in @Beforeclass annotation.Is there any way how can I achieve this?In google, all i can see is examples about inluding/excluding methods in @Test annotation ,but i am unable to find how we can include/exclude methods present in  other annotations like before class,before method(Other then test annotation).

Comment: Also , I want to know how to abort execution if any class present in testng xml file fails?

Comment: Could you explain what is your goal? Using the before method as a test? Run it before a test from another class? BTW, you should share a sample.

Comment: Actually, my code was reading data from excel which is in beforeclass annotation.So i wanted only that part of the class but not the main Test methods from that class.

Comment: In that case, just move the business code into a util method and use it from the before class method or anywhere you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you cannot control beforeClass, beforeMethod as they trigger automatically. If you want to control your method, you need to add @Test before it and then only you can ignore/include them.

If everytime, you want to execute them then you dont need to include them, they will get triggered always without mentioning them in testNG.xml

Comment: Thanks Gaurav, hence the include/exclude tags in testng.xml file are only for methods with @test annotation..Right?